# What is main purpose of mirroring in MapR hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, mirroring, mapr

I am reading about mirroring in MapR. I have doubt that What is main purpose of mirroring in MapR Hadoop distribution. Why we need to mirror volumes, when we still have replication of data.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand from the docs? *You can use mirror volumes in the same cluster (local mirroring) to provide **local load balancing** by using mirror volumes to serve read requests for the most frequently accessed data in the cluster. You can also mirror volumes on a separate cluster (remote mirroring) for **backup and disaster readiness purposes***

Comment: I got that, but when we have replication in Hadoop. What’s the point of mirroring the volume. ?

Comment: HDFS Replicas aren't used for "accessing frequently used data" or backups to remote clusters. It's only for load balancing client requests and ensuring a rack or datanode failure will not cause data loss. To backup to remote clusters, distcp is a manual task compared to some scheduled rsync-like mirroring job